# Multiple Constructor and null value

Tags: android, constructor

1: Start Quiz class from a class:

```
Med.setQuiz(new Quiz(Cat, null));
```

Quiz class:

```
public Quiz(final String category, TextView outputTxt) {
        MyTxt = outputTxt; 
            StartAct(category);
}
```

2: Start Quiz class from another class:

```
Quiz MyNewQ = new Quiz(null, Txt);
```

**Firstly** : I started class that set some values with **StartAct(category);**

**Then** I used class again :  **Quiz(null, Txt);**  BUT when I used it, **StartAct values set to null**.

But I want to use values that I set in first class  [ *Quiz(Cat, null)* ]

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static value like this:

```
public class Quiz{

    private static String category;

    public Quiz(final String category, TextView outputTxt) {

            // check category is not null or empty, don't set if it is
            // which means that we must call the constructor with a valid category
            // the first time or perhaps set a default value
            if(category!=null && !category.equals("")){
                Quiz.category = category;
            }
            MyTxt = outputTxt; 
            StartAct(Quiz.category);

    }
}
```